# tinyproxy: How to manually install the most recent version 1.11.0 on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, proxy, tinyproxy

**I would like to install the most recent tinyproxy version 1.11.0 on Ubuntu. How can I do that?**

Unfortunetly does  `sudo apt update; sudo apt install tinyproxy -y;` not work for me and only gives me the most recent stable version 1.10.0 from 2018.

So I tried to download and unzip the most recent version on GitHub
https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/releases

But I couldn't get it to work properly installed yet.

**What I tried so far:**

```
sudo apt update;
... [loading the unzipped tinyproxy 1.11.0 folder via own GitHub repo]
cd OwnGitHubRepo/tinyproxy-1.11.0
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
sudo apt install autoconf -y
autoconf
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The installation seems to have been working somehow as `tinyproxy -v`  returns: `tinyproxy 1.11.0`

But I now can not run following command which I would usually do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tinyproxy restart;
```

As there is **no tinyproxy folder inside /etc/** listed yet. :/

---

(Also `sudo lsof -i:8888` doesn't show any listing server yet)

---

Documentations:

http://tinyproxy.github.io/

---

Tried under AWS EC2 Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure you update the system with the latest packages

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-209:~$ sudo su -
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~#
```

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# apt-get update
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You can reboot the server if a new kernel is available

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# reboot
```

2. Install the build tools:

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# apt-get install build-essential
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# apt-get install autoconf
```

3. Download the source code and build the software

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# wget https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/releases/download/1.11.0/tinyproxy-1.11.0.tar.bz2
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# tar -jxvf tinyproxy-1.11.0.tar.bz2
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# cd tinyproxy-1.11.0/
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# ./configure
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# make
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# make install
```

Important directories/files to track:

```
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /usr/bin/install -c tinyproxy '/usr/local/bin'

 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/tinyproxy'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 debug.html default.html stats.html '/usr/local/share/tinyproxy'

 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/etc/tinyproxy'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tinyproxy.conf '/usr/local/etc/tinyproxy'

 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man5'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tinyproxy.conf.5 '/usr/local/share/man/man5'

 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man8'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tinyproxy.8 '/usr/local/share/man/man8'

 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/doc/tinyproxy'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 AUTHORS NEWS README README.md '/usr/local/share/doc/tinyproxy'
```

4. Configure the software

Symlink the configuration folder

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# ln -s /usr/local/etc/tinyproxy /etc/
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# ls -la /etc/ | grep tinyproxy
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root         24 Apr  3 09:53 tinyproxy -> /usr/local/etc/tinyproxy
```

Check the nobody user group

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# cat /etc/passwd | grep nobody
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# cat /etc/group | grep 65534
nogroup:x:65534:
```

Since nobody is assigned to the nogroup group, change the Group element in tinyproxy config from nobody group to nogroup

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# sed -i s/'Group nobody'/'Group nogroup'/g /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf
```

Configure the rest of tinyproxy to your expectations (here is the minimal setup)

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# cat /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf | grep -v "^#\|^$"
User nobody
Group nogroup
Port 8888
Timeout 600
DefaultErrorFile "/usr/local/share/tinyproxy/default.html"
StatFile "/usr/local/share/tinyproxy/stats.html"
LogLevel Info
MaxClients 100
Allow 127.0.0.1
Allow ::1
ViaProxyName "tinyproxy"
```

Test the connection

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# tinyproxy -d -c /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf
NOTICE    Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: Initializing tinyproxy ...
NOTICE    Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: Reloading config file
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: Setting "Via" header to 'tinyproxy'
NOTICE    Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: Reloading config file finished
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: listen_sock called with addr = '(NULL)'
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: trying to listen on host[0.0.0.0], family[2], socktype[1], proto[6]
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: listening on fd [3]
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: trying to listen on host[::], family[10], socktype[1], proto[6]
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: listening on fd [4]
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: Now running as group "nogroup".
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: Now running as user "nobody".
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: Setting the various signals.
INFO      Apr 03 09:56:13.294 [8179]: Starting main loop. Accepting connections.

CTRL+C
```

5. Create a service to run tinyproxy

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# nano /lib/systemd/system/tinyproxy.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=tinyproxy service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=nobody
Group=nogroup
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/tinyproxy -d -c /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

6. Start the service and check if everything is working fine

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# systemctl enable tinyproxy.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tinyproxy.service → /lib/systemd/system/tinyproxy.service.
```

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# systemctl status tinyproxy.service
● tinyproxy.service - tinyproxy service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tinyproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-04-03 10:00:20 UTC; 5s ago
   Main PID: 8236 (tinyproxy)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1145)
     Memory: 1.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/tinyproxy.service
             └─8236 /usr/local/bin/tinyproxy -d -c /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf

Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: Setting "Via" header to 'tinyproxy'
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: NOTICE    Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: Reloading config file finished
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: listen_sock called with addr = '(NULL)'
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: trying to listen on host[0.0.0.0], family[2], socktype[1], proto[6]
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: listening on fd [3]
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: trying to listen on host[::], family[10], socktype[1], proto[6]
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: listening on fd [4]
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: Not running as root, so not changing UID/GID.
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: Setting the various signals.
Apr 03 10:00:20 ip-172-30-2-209 tinyproxy[8236]: INFO      Apr 03 10:00:20.980 [8236]: Starting main loop. Accepting connections.
```

Install net-tools to check the listening ports

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# apt-get install net-tools
```

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# netstat -napt | grep LISTEN | grep tinyproxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8236/tinyproxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      8236/tinyproxy
```

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# lsof -i:8888
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
tinyproxy 8236 nobody    3u  IPv4  34119      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
tinyproxy 8236 nobody    4u  IPv6  34120      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
```

7. Extras

a) Logging and Pid file

Prepare pid and log directories

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# mkdir /var/run/tinyproxy/
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# mkdir /var/log/tinyproxy/
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# chown -R nobody:nogroup /var/run/tinyproxy/
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# chown -R nobody:nogroup /var/log/tinyproxy/
```

Add pid and log parameters into tinyproxy config

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0#
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# cat /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf | grep ^LogFile
LogFile "/var/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log"
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# cat /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf | grep ^PidFile
PidFile "/var/run/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.pid"
```

Restart service

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~/tinyproxy-1.11.0# systemctl restart tinyproxy.service
```

b) Process limits

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# ps aux | grep tinyproxy
nobody     64427  9.8  0.5 789836 10232 ?        Ssl  12:11   0:00 /usr/local/bin/tinyproxy -d -c /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf
root       65436  0.0  0.0   7696   644 pts/0    S+   12:11   0:00 grep --color=auto tinyproxy
```

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# cat /proc/64427/limits | grep "Max processes\|Max open files"
Max processes             7151                 7151                 processes
Max open files            1024                 524288               files
```

To bump up those, edit the /lib/systemd/system/tinyproxy.service file and add the following lines in the [Service] section

```
[Service]
...
LimitNOFILE=700000
LimitNPROC=700000
...
```

Then reload systemd and restart the service

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# systemctl daemon-reload
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# systemctl restart tinyproxy.service
```

Check the results

```
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# ps axu | grep tinyproxy
nobody     68439  0.6  0.1 533092  3068 ?        Ssl  12:13   0:00 /usr/local/bin/tinyproxy -d -c /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf
root       68490  0.0  0.0   7696   656 pts/0    S+   12:13   0:00 grep --color=auto tinyproxy
root@ip-172-30-2-209:~# cat /proc/68439/limits | grep "Max processes\|Max open files"
Max processes             700000               700000               processes
Max open files            700000               700000               files
```

Comment: Great answer!  In step 4, when editing the tinyproxy.conf, it should be `Group nogroup`

Comment: You're right. Changing that. Thank you!

Comment: For ver.1.11.1 the step 3 is wrong. There are no such files in the archive located in the root of the extracted archive. Tinyproxy is already installed are make install in /usr/local/bin/, all the other files absent. Also right after install is starts, so it won't bind to oport anymore untill you kill the process